# ControllerContext Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
PDFController Ctrl = new PDFController();
            byte[] ArquivoPDF = Ctrl.GerarPDF(xml);
```

Esta parte acima esta na WebApi, onde crio uma nova instancia do Controller para utilizar a função que se encontra nele. O código abaixo ja é a parte do controller:

```
public class PDFController : Controller
{
 public string RenderizaHtmlComoString(string NomeView, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, NomeView);

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Só que na parte que vou formar a variável viewResult, da um erro e diz que o ControllerContext não pode ser nulo.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?
*Esse Controller não esta vinculado a nenhuma View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua ControllerContext neste caso sempre será nula porque você está instanciando a controller "manualmente".

Geralmente a controller é criada por um IControllerFactoy que normalmente é o DafaultControllerFactory, ele cria a controller com todas as dependências necessárias que inclui o ControllerContext.

Normalmente quando precisa-se de métodos comuns entre controllers, cria-se uma controller base que é herdada nas demais controller. No seu caso ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
{
    // GET: Base
    public byte[] GerarPDF(string content)
    {
        //Código que gera o pdf.

        return new byte[] { };
    }
}
    public class ControllerA : BaseController
{
    public byte[] AlgumMetodo()
    {
        return GerarPDF("");
    }
}

public class ControllerB : BaseController
{
    public string AlgumOutroMetodo()
    {
        byte[] pdf = GerarPDF("");

        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso eu preciso chamar essas funções do controller de dentro de uma Api, saberia como posso fazer isso? foi até por esse motivo que eu criei uma instancia do controller, para tentar fazer com q eu consegui-se chamar o metodo.

Comment: Realmente neste caso são controllers de tipos diferentes. Neste caso eu colocaria este método em uma classe a parte para ser utilizada nas controller. Não sei como está o código, então não sei se é possível por causa de algum dependência.

Comment: Então o que está me impedindo é que este método do PDF q eu postei, ele retorna uma view, só que, eu até consigo retornar a view mesmo fora do controller, só que ela contém algumas TempData e algumas ViewBag para que sua montagem seja completa. Ai já encontro outro problema, que não achei uma maneira de utilizar as TempData e as ViewBag fora do controller... A não ser que possua alguma forma de substitui-las por outras opções que até então não conheço.

Comment: Bom realmente acho que você está com um probleminha de arquitetura aí... esse seu método está muito acoplado à um ambiente, que no caso é o web já que TemData e ViewBag geralmente são utilizados para passar informações para view. Neste caso requer uma análise mais aprofundada para desacoplar isso e separar em uma classe responsável por isso, principio da responsabilidade única (SOLID).

Comment: Sim, está com alguns probleminhas mesmo, é que na verdade já tinha essa consciência que teria que mexer na estrutura, mas estava na esperança de que houve-se algum jeito que não fosse necessário fazer essas mudanças, mas obrigado vou começar a estudar a estrutura para fazer os ajustes. Valeu :D

Comment: Boa sorte aí, e com calma dá pra separar isso com certeza. ;)